# How to JTable print PageSetup?

Tags: java, oracle, printing, installation

How can I set the Border measures in the layout tab?

[image]

```
// print JTable
PrintRequestAttributeSet set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
set.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
try {
    tableToPrint.print(JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL, null, null, true, set, false);
} catch (PrinterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Previously searched:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/AttributeSet.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/DocAttributeSet.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/PrintJobAttributeSet.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/PrintRequestAttributeSet.html

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for HashPrintRequestAttributeSet Attributes:

```
new MediaPrintableArea(int,int,int,int,MediaPrintableArea.MM)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/Attribute.html